# Howto configure Runtime Version which builds Resources.Designer.cs in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I've somehow screwed up my visual stuio 2010  installation. (I installed and uninstalled the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview)

If i now build a simple forms project where a form has "localizable=true", i got the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The reason is the Runtime version which creates the Properties\Resources.Designer.cs. 
In my case it is Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17020 instead of Runtime Version: 4.0.30319.239.

Where can in configure the version used to create those Designer files in visual studio?

Comment: Found a solution. I'll post it as soon as stackoverflow allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem:
I uninstalled the following tools

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Client Profile Developer Preview
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Extended Developer Preview

Then i've reinstalled Visual Studio 2010.

After this, i don't get any errors related to the resource version.

btw: this also solved a problem when building a solution with msbuild 4.0 for target version 3.5. 
The error message i got:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Data.Entity.target(50,5): error MSB4044: The "EntityClean" task was not given a value for the required parameter "ResourceOutputPath"
```

And this disappeared after removing the 4.5 stuff and reinstalling VS2010